# what is the best way to retrive information in a graph through has Step

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm using titan graph db with tinkerpop plugin. What is the best way to retrieve a vertex using has step?

Assuming employeeId is a unique attribute which has a unique vertex centric index defined.

Is it through label
i.e g.V().has(label,'employee').has('employeeId','emp123')
g.V().has('employee','employeeId','emp123')

(or)
is it better to retrieve a vertex based on Unique properties directly?
i.e g.V().has('employeeId','emp123')

Which one of the two is the quickest and better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have 2 options to create the index:

1. `mgmt.buildIndex('byEmployeeId', Vertex.class).addKey(employeeId).buildCompositeIndex()`
2. `mgmt.buildIndex('byEmployeeId', Vertex.class).addKey(employeeId).indexOnly(employee).buildCompositeIndex()`

For option 1 it doesn't really matter which query you're going to use. For option 2 it's mandatory to use `g.V().has('employee','employeeId','emp123')`.

Note that `g.V().hasLabel('employee').has('employeeId','emp123')` will *NOT* select all employees first. Titan is smart enough to apply those filter conditions, that can leverage an index, first.

One more thing I want to point out is this: The whole point of `indexOnly()` is to allow to share properties between different types of vertices. So instead of calling the property `employeeId`, you could call it `uuid` and also use it for employers, companies, etc:

```
mgmt.buildIndex('employeeById', Vertex.class).addKey(uuid).indexOnly(employee).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.buildIndex('employerById', Vertex.class).addKey(uuid).indexOnly(employer).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.buildIndex('companyById', Vertex.class).addKey(uuid).indexOnly(company).buildCompositeIndex()
```

Your queries will then always have this pattern: `g.V().has('<label>','<prop-key>','<prop-value>')`. This is in fact the only way to go in DSE Graph, since we got completely rid of *global indexes* that span across all types of vertices. At first I really didn't like this decision, but meanwhile I have to agree that this is so much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you much Daniel, such a nice explanation. It cleared the clouds for me. Now we can write our gremlin queries in a way as to suit both Titan and DSE syntax as much as possible, so that migrating to DSE (if inevitable) we could do with minimum tussle :)

Answer (score 1):

The second option `g.V().has('employeeId','emp123')` is better as long as the property `employeeId` has been [indexed](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html) for better performance.

This is because each step in a gremlin traversal acts a filter. So when you say:

```
g.V().has(label,'employee').has('employeeId','emp123')
```

You first go to all the vertices with the label `employee` and then from the employee vertices you find `emp123`.

With `g.V().has('employeeId','emp123')` a composite index allows you to go directly to the correct vertex.

**Edit:**

As Daniel has pointed out in his answer, Titan is actually smart enough to not visit all employees and leverages the index immediately. So in this case it appears there is little difference between the traversals. I personally favour using direct global indices without labels (i.e. the first traversal) but that is just a preference when using Titan, I like to keep steps and filters to a minimum.

Comment: I agree with Filipe until recently and this was my thought process too. But after going through the DSE graph video tutorials at https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds330-datastax-enterprise-graph I am now dubious because the indexing there happens to be completely vertex centric and the examples in the videos are also advocating the first syntax `g.V().hasLabel('employee').has('employeeId','emp123')`. Now I am not  quiet sure if the reasoning above stands good! I know the indexing is entirely different in DSE graph and Titan, but want to be doubly sure that approach 2 is correct!!

Comment: @Phani I believe that the 1st traversal I suggested is better but that is exclusive to Titan. I have not used DSE much so I am not sure how they are doing the indexing, it may very well be vertex centric. Thanks for the link though, I will check it out later.